# C : Pass Array of string as function argument

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, arguments

So what I have is a file **main.c** which is including a header file I made **utils.h**, containing forward references to functions in my source file **utils.c**

#### In utils.c:

I have a function that accepts an array of string as an argument, and prints it out as a menu:

```
void showMenu(const char *menu[])
{
    int menulen = sizeof(menu)/sizeof(*menu);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < menulen; i++)
    {
        printf("[%d] .. %s\n", (i+1), menu[i]);
    }
}
```

#### In main.c:

I simply call this function:

```
const char *menu[] =
{
        "Customers",
        "Orders",
        "Products"
};

int main(void)
{
    showTitle("Customer Orders System");
    int menulen = sizeof(menu)/sizeof(*menu);
    showMenu(menu);
    getch();
}
```

#### My Problem:

My **showMenu** function is calculating the length of the array, and then iterating through it, printing the strings. This used to work when the function was in **main.c**, but I am required to organize this project in separate files.

The length is now being calculated as 1. After doing some debugging, I think this is a pointer-related problem, but I seem to resolve it. The argument for **showMenu** after the call is of type

```
const char** menu
```

having only the first element of my original array.

I tried deferencing the argument, passing it a pointer of the array, and both at the same time.
Strangely enough, the same line of code works in the main function.
I really don't want to have to resolve this problem by adding a length of array argument to the function.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: +1 for your concise description of the problem, for your own analysis of it, and for nicely formatted code that actually allows others to reproduce the described behavior.

Comment: Thanks! I know what it's like trying to answer to a typical non-formatted 3-line description of a problem. Plus it makes boring to read.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because arrays *decay* into pointers to their first element when passed to a function like yours, and there is no information retained about the number of elements. In the scope where the array is declared, this decay hasn't happened, so `sizeof` works.

You must either add length of array as an extra argument, or make sure the array is terminated by an appropriate *sentinel* value. One popular such value is `NULL`, i.e. you make sure the last valid index holds a string pointer whose value is `NULL`, which then indicates "no more data, stop":

```
const char *menu[] =
{
    "Customers",
    "Orders",
    "Products",
    NULL /* This is a sentinel, to mark the end of the array. */
};
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure I understood you correctly.
Appending NULL to my array violates the type of elements in my array, as told to me by my compiler. creating a 'char *p = NULL' and appending 'p' to my array gives me the same error.